# Should i use a pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

So I'm receiving a string from twitch irc and based on that command I execute some code. The question is can I simplify my code or use a pattern. The thing is that most of the commands have the same code and only the reply changes. You can see the code below. It looks very messy and adding new commands or functionality will probably be a pain(if I have 200 or more commands) plus most of the code is the same.

```
public void onCommand(User user, Channel channel, String command)
    {

        // some if statements 

        switch (command.toLowerCase()){
        case "hi":{

            //some simple action
        }
        case "fire":{

            vote(60, channel, "fire")
        }
        ...

        //timeout
    }

    void vote(int duration, final Channel channel, String voteFor){
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //start voting
            }, duration);

            switch (voteFor){
                case "fire":{
                    if (voteYes > voteNo) {
                        //some action
                    }else
                        //some action
                    break;
                }
                ...
    }
```

P.S I tried using the strategy pattern but it felt like there is no need for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an interface, say `Command`

```
public interface Command {

    void execute(User user, Channel channel);

}
```

Then, create a map from command names to actual commands.

```
Map<String, Command> commands;
```

You could populate the map as follows

```
commands.put("fire", (user, channel) -> {/** Do something with user and channel **/})
```

Then, for your `onCammnd`, you could do

```
commands.get(command.toLowerCase()).execute(user, channel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map:

```
class CommandProcessor {

  interface Command {
    String executeForKey();
    void execute(User user, Channel channel);
  }

  class OnFireCommand implements Command {
    public String executeForKey() { return "fire"; }
    public void execute() {}
  }

  Map<String, Command> map = new HashMap<>();

  CommandProcessor() {
    // this will become a simple listing of commands
    put(new OnFireCommand())
  }

  void put(Command c) {
    map.put(c.executeForKey(), c);
  }

  public void onCommand(User user, Channel channel, String command) {
    this.map.get(command).execute(user, channel);
  }
}
```